# The version of the artifactItem is not defaulting to the version from the dependencies or dependencyManagement when we use multiple profiles?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-profiles

I'm working with maven.

As present in this link : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html (Second case) , we can remove the  tag present if the artifact is listed as a dependency. Because the version of the artifactItem will default to the version from the dependencies.

But this is not the case when profiles are used.

I'm using two profiles inside which I'm adding dependency. My pom is like this :

```
<profile>
        <id>buildDependency</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>maven.dependency</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.marshy</groupId>
                <artifactId>marshy1</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.5</version>
            </dependency>
```

Now if i remove the  tag from the  thinking that it will take the value from here, it's throwing error stating "Failed to collect dependencies for ......."

How can i make this work for profiles?

Answer (score 0):

I edited the example to specify the junit dependency inside the profile dependencies tag. See this example `pom.xml`. I did not run into any problems doing this, so there might be a different issue in your pom (that you only posted part of).

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>build-dependency-example</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                                    <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
                                    <destFileName>optional-new-name.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/wars</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>buildDependency</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                <property>
                    <name>maven.dependency</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.1</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```